# Cannot compile Tabularray with a math environment in it and a \NewColumnType

Tags: math-mode, tabularray

I have this code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\NewColumnType{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\def\myformula{Area = side \times side \\ Perimeter = side \times 4}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={cX},
            row{2}={C,fg=white,bg=black}
        }
        {One} & {Two} & \SetCell[c=2]{C}{\myformula} \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

This code doesn't compile, the most relevant error during compilation ( reported on row 12 ) is:

```
Missing $ inserted. \end
```

I understand that using a math environment inside a tabular one is more complicated than usual, for this reason I tried to use `\NewColumnType`to make my life easier but apparently I'm missing something and I already tried a lot of variations.

What I'm missing ? Something to do with how Latex3 works ?

Comment: Welcome to teX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Which version of `\tabularray` you use?
- Your MWE (Minimal Working Example) contain many errors. From definition of `myformula` to number of defined columns ...
- Syntax of `tabularray` package differ from syntax of "classic" packages for tables. For example, it define option for math mode of columns. For details see package documentation.
- I guess, that you looking for the following result:

[image]

With recent version of `\tabularray` (2022A) your MWE should be:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\def\myformula{\begin{gathered}
    \mathrm{Area} = \mathrm{side} \times \mathrm{side} \\ \mathrm{Perimeter} = \mathrm{side} \times 4
                \end{gathered}}

\begin{document}
\noindent%    
\begin{tblr}{colspec={cc X[c, m] X[c, m] },
                  row{1}={fg=white,bg=black}
                }
One &   Two & \SetCell[c=2]{c,$$}{\myformula} 
                    &       \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
I cases, when you like to have aligned equations at `=` sign, you need to replace `gathered` with `aligned` environment (both are defined in `amsmath` package):

```
\def\myformula{\begin{aligned}
    \mathrm{Area}   & = \mathrm{side} \times \mathrm{side}
\mathrm{Perimeter}  & = \mathrm{side} \times 4
               \end{aligned}}
```

using above in suggested MWE gives the following result.

[image]

If you still have some open problems, I suggest you to ask new question where clearly (maybe with link to this) where clearly explain what is your problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is what I found `Package: tabularray 2022-03-01 v2022A Typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3` , I'm also looking for a 2x2 table with the last row with both columns collapsed into 1. I would also like to aling the formulas according to the `=`equal sign and the classic `&=`doesn't work.

Comment: @pafao, your question is not very clear, so answer is as it is (based on guessing. For aligning of equations you should use `aligned` environment `myformula definition. See edited answer (will appear soon).

Comment: What I meant was: a 2x2 table with 3 cells in total, first row with 2 cells, the second row with just 1 ( 2 columns collapsed into 1 ). Anyway thanks for the suggestions, any good links on where to find more docs about this ?

Comment: @pafao, as I say, please ask new question (if you will stuck at writing it) , where you show what you tray so far. In above answer you have solid skeleton for design desired table :-).